# Tank_Auth Shows warnings when user registers and activation fails with "Incorrect or Expired" message

Tags: php, membership, tankauth

I don't do much PHP but I saw this library called, [Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) for Code Ignitor and it looks promising. I am trying to use it in my project but I am having some issues. After following all the installation instructions (there aren't many) I tried registering a user. When I submit the registration form I am presented with several warnings on the screen.

Most of them are this:

> Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Denver' for 'MDT/-6.0/DST' instead

The one other is this:

> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Nick/Sites/HoneyDo/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Despite the above messages a confirmation email is sent to my inbox. The confirmation email contains a link that basically says click here to confirm registration. However, when I do, the page just says "The activation code you entered is either incorrect or expired."

Is there anyone out there using this that has seen these issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you modified the codeigniter base at all before/after installing this, what version of php, and what version of codeigniter?

Comment: Im using codeignitor 2.0.2 and just.. No I did not change the CI code base. This is a clean installation. I'm trying to start a project from scratch with tank auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before making a call to the date() I added a call to the  date_default_timezone_set() function. After setting my timezone the errors went away. [Default Time Zone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)